# 20140328 Google SDK issues

Tags: android, sdk, eclipse-plugin, google-play-services

Today I just upgraded to the latest SDK and now I am having issues with the google-play-services_lib. I can't import the library into my project as I previously did. Has anyone else run into this type of issue?

Comment: Have you installed required libraries inside SDKManakger-> Extras??

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had the corrupted previous version of the project in my work space. I removed it and then was able to load in the new version.